Testing an opaque type's internals
First: What is an opaque pointer in C?
Now when it comes to testing such a type, I know of 3 ways:

Include the source file (the one containing the definition of the type and the functions that work with it) directory into the test source file. (This is the easiest, but often discouraged without presenting any rationale).

Make public accessors that are conditionally available (i.e. only if if LIB_TEST is defined before including its header).

Make a separate "lib-test.h" header file that contains the public accessors.


The last two avoid making the accessors part of the public API (we're speaking of the case where the clients have no business knowing anything about the opaque type's internals, and shouldn't be provided with any accessors).
What is the usual approach (or the good approach) in C? Does one way have more upsides/downsides than the other?
As an example, say I have this struct:
typedef struct arena {
    size_t count;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t current;
    size_t last_alloc_size;
    M_Pool *pools[];
} Arena;

and a function associated with it:
void arena_reset(Arena *arena)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arena->count; ++i) {
        arena->pools[i]->offset = 0;
    }
    arena->current = 1;
}

Now I wish to assert that arena_reset() actually has set the offset field of all the arena's pools to 0, and the arena's current field to 1. Including the API (header file) that this library provides is of no good, because only a forward declaration of the struct type has been provided, and its members can not be accessed.

I am asking about good practices. If the question is deemed opinion-based (which I do not believe), I will take it down myself.

Unit-testing can be done two ways: Either as internal testing, where the tests have knowledge of the internal structure and private data and functions; Or using only the public API. But I would really recommend you do unit-testing for both.

What is it about the type itself that you think you want to test?  It is usually functions that we want to test.

@JohnBollinger I have added an example. Is it clearer now?

If you make the "hidden" accessors publicly visible by including them in the public header, people will (ab)use that information.  What you do instead depends on the coding conventions in use for the project and the size of the problem.  A non-public header available only to the implementation is certainly an option (option 3).  Embedding test code in the implementation file is another.  Including the implementation in the test code is another — it is effective because general users of the code won't want to include the source but the test code needs the implementation information.

See also How to test a static function? — although it discusses static functions, they are just one specific example of "hidden information that needs to be accessed for testing".

Duplicate at Codidact. Please refrain from cross posting like that, for license reasons if nothing else. Historically, cross-posting like this is a good way to get yourself in trouble at both sites. Because how are the mods of each respective site to know if these are the same user or if the question was actually plagiarized without attribution?

@Lundin Acknowledged.

If you want to test internal details of a source module (i.e. as functions or objects declared as static, or struct definitions defined only in the source module), this is one of the rare cases where it makes sense to #include a .c file.
So for example if the struct and function above reside in arena.c, your test module could do something like this:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "arena.c"

void test_arena_reset()
{
    int pool_cnt = 3;
    Arena *p = malloc(sizeof *p + (pool_cnt * sizeof(M_Pool));
    p->count = pool_cnt;
    for (int i = 0; i < pool_cnt; i++) {
        p->pools[i]->offset = 1;
    }
    p->current = 0;

    arena_reset(p);

    assert(p->current == 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < pool_cnt; i++) {
        assert(p->pools[i]->offset == 0);
    }
}


See How to test a static function?

The conventional mechanism for making type definitions available to multiple translation units is to put them in a header, which each TU that needs the definitions #includes.  Nothing about opaque types makes that different.  It's just a question of to which translation units the type is opaque, and to which it isn't.
If you want to provide for tests included with the sources to pierce the opacity of your opaque type, then put the type definition in a private header.  Let those source files that should be able to see the type definition include that header.  Others don't. If the project is a library, then the private header is not installed with the regular library headers.
This is different from all of the options presented in the question, though it has similarities to both (1) and (3).  Note in particular that

the private header in question would be a genuine header -- no function definitions.  It would provide the definition of the erstwhile opaque type instead of a source file doing that.

there are no accessor functions defined or needed beyond any that would be provided anyway.


